# Is there a way to map FN to MenuKey without outside software?

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys, remapping, keymap

My new Rosewill mech keyboard has an FN key instead of Menu Key (aka context key or apps key). Is there any way I can map that to the Menu Key without downloading outside software?  Unfortunately can't install AutoHotkey on my work laptop. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, the FN key modifies the keypresses before sending them to the computer, so the computer doesn't even know about it. Needs confirmation though, I'm not sure about it (that's why I don't post an answer).

Comment: @NathanShiraini what if I were to map the right Alt instead?

Comment: The right Alt key will work, this one is sent directly to the OS, and some softwares make the difference between left and right Ctrl or Alt.